# rTypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object python

Tags: python, re, ifconfig

Я-новокек, поэтому прошу не осуждать. Цель программы - автоматическая смена MAC-адреса.
Ошибка возникает насколько я понял из-за того, что тип данных записанных в переменной не соответствует тому, который ждет питон. **Я **не знаю** как поменять его.**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
import optparse
import re
def get_arguments():
    parser = optparse.OptionParser()
    parser.add_option("-i", "--interface", dest ="interface", help="interface to change its MAC address")
    parser.add_option("-m", "--mac", dest="new_mac", help="new MAC address")
    (options, arguments) = parser.parse_args()
    if not options.interface:
        parser.error("[-] Please specify an interface, use --help for more info.")
    elif not options.new_mac:
        parser.error("[-] Please specify a new mac, use --help for more info.")
    return options
def change_mac(interface, new_mac):
    print("[+] Changing MAC address for " + interface + "to" + new_mac)
    subprocess.call("ifconfig eth0 down", shell=True)
    subprocess.call("ifconfig eth0 hw ether **тут мак адрес**", shell=True)
    subprocess.call("ifconfig eth0 up", shell=True)
options = get_arguments()
# change_mac(options.interface, options.new_mac)
ifconfig_result = subprocess.check_output(["ifconfig", options.interface])
#print(ifconfig_result)
mac_address_search_result = re.search(r"\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w", ifconfig_result)
print(mac_address_search_result.group(0))
```

Ошибка:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
> "/root/PycharmProjects/lesson2/mac_changer.py", line 31, in  mac_address_search_result = re.search(r"\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w", ifconfig_result) File "/usr/lib/python3.9/re.py",
> line 201, in search return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string) TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object

Comment: Есть полное описание ошибки? в какой строке падает?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/lesson2/mac_changer.py", line 31, in <module>
    mac_address_search_result = re.search(r"\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w", ifconfig_result)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/re.py", line 201, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object

Comment: строка которая вызывает ошибку: 
mac_address_search_result = re.search(r"\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w", ifconfig_result)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас переменная `ifconfig_result` содержит байтовую последовательность. Нужно ее привести к строке, к которой применяете регулярное выражение. Попробуйте так

```py
import sys
ifconfig_result = subprocess.check_output(["ifconfig", options.interface]).decode(sys.stdout.encoding)
```

Comment: сделал так, теперь другая ошибка: 

traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/lesson2/mac_changer.py", line 28, in <module>
    ifconfig_result = subprocess.check_output(["ifconfig", options.interface]).decode(sys.stdout.encoding)
NameError: name 'sys' is not defined

Comment: @Sman подправил ответ

Comment: импортировал sys, все пошло, спасибо!!

Comment: Пользуйтесь, на здоровье